# redirect is not done after successful login

Tags: angular, authentication, nebular, ngx-admin

im working on ngx admin i use nebular login after a successful login it should redirect to pages path but it doesnt work

```
strategies: [
      NbPasswordAuthStrategy.setup({
        name: "email",
        token: {
          class: NbAuthJWTToken,
          key: "token",
        },
        baseEndpoint: "http://10.22.0.211",
        login: {
          endpoint: "/tokens",
          method: "post",
        },
      }),
    ],
    forms: {
      login: {
        redirectDelay: 500,
        strategy: "email",
        // rememberMe: false,
        showMessage: {
          success: true,
          error: true,
        },
        redirect: {
          success: "/pages/",
          failure: null,
        },
      },
    },
```